ubuntu 24.04 installation crashing with FED
First time I tried to install fully encrypted disk was not available, it was greyed out. It's a little research I discovered that you could not select third party drivers during installation if you intended to select fully encrypted disk.  But I installed anyway just for practice and it went rather smoothly. But then I put a different motherboard in and tried again. This time the installation app kept crashing. It is fairly common when using used PC components for things to be a bit unstable at first so I kept trying but I finally had to switch back to my original motherboard. Again I had issues but with some perseverance it finally worked sort of. The installation app kept crashing. I've never used secure boot or TPM. I discovered it's very important to go into the BIOS and choose clear under the TPM setting before trying to reinstall.  I also discovered the boot process is substantially different. The F12 option on my Dell Optiplex do not provide the same options as before. Unless formatted with gpt and installed with UEFI boot options a drive will not show up in the menu.  I finally gave up trying to get the installation application to complete without error messages and just accepted it when I was finally able to reboot into a working operating system. It seemed okay but I soon discovered there was no sound from the HDMI sound card.
I have a question. Shoud I collect output from journalctl during installation to help the developers or do they get all they need automatically? Is there any reason doing this will interfere with the installation app? It crashed a lot whether or not I did this and I am not sure exactly why.
I intend to do several more installation over the next week and I want to help the developers any way I can.
Peace

I spent several hours trying to get this working before I rediscovered some tools I not used in a long time.
First I ran sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
and then I started an app called aptitude and used it to reinstall all installed packages.
The sound now works even from the hdmi sound card. (I love pipewire.)
